# Switching between doing something and not doing it within $k$ steps in LTL

Tags: linear-temporal-logic

Imagine that we are designing a system in which we have the action to brake or not brake. How can we write an LTL specification that guarantees that we cannot switch between braking and not braking within three time steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply require that whenever there is a switch (i.e., the braking status changed from one to another), the status will not change for the next three steps.
Technically, let $b$ denote the propositions that brake is on, then we have the following:
$$G((\neg b\wedge Xb)\to (XXb\wedge XXXb) )\wedge G((b\wedge X\neg b)\to (XX\neg b\wedge XXX\neg b) )$$
Note that you can put the two conditions inside one $G$ operator. I just find this way easier to read.